# Mapping field-errors with different validators

Tags: spring-mvc

My usecase: a single html-form can triggered as a save or an update event. Depending on the event the validation is is performed by a different validator. This works so far with the following code. The only problem I have, that I want the field-errors to be mapped in all cases to "saveDto", so I can map them in my form.

Any hints welcome.

```
  @Inject
  private SaveValidator saveValidator;

  @Inject
  private UpdateValidator updateValidator;

  @RequestMapping(value = EVENT_SAVE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  protected String doSave(@Valid @ModelAttribute("saveDto") final SaveDto saveDto,
      final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
      // ...
    }

  }

  @RequestMapping(value = EVENT_UPDATE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  protected String doUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("updateDto") final SaveDto saveDto,
      final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
      // ...
    }

  }


  @InitBinder("saveDto")
  protected void initSaveValidator(final WebDataBinder binder)
  {
    binder.addValidators(saveValidator);
  }

  @InitBinder("updateDto")
  protected void initUpdateValidator(final WebDataBinder binder)
  {
    binder.addValidators(updateValidator);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the hibernate validation group feature along with @Validated annotation